# How can I keep the nav bar in my React app from re-rendering on page refresh?

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to React and am trying to figure out how to keep the state of my nav bar on page refresh.

I have a nav bar that has "Home" and "Projects", each linking to their respective pages (./Home.js and ./Projects.js).  When the user is on the Home page, only the "Projects" link shows, and when the user is on the Projects page only the "Home" link shows.

The code I have works just fine... until the page is refreshed; then the nav bar re-renders to its original state, no matter which page it is on.  How can I make sure the nav bar does not re-render on the page if the browser is reloaded?  I understand WHY the code behaves this way, but can't figure out a solution to make the nav bar not re-render on page refresh.

Router.js code:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Link, Route, BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./Home.js";
import Projects from "./Projects.js";

class Router extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      showHome: false,
      showProjects: true
    };

    this.handleHomeClick = this.handleHomeClick.bind(this);
    this.handleProjectsClick = this.handleProjectsClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleHomeClick() {
    this.setState(() => ({
      showHome: false,
      showProjects: true
    }));
  }

  handleProjectsClick() {
    this.setState(() => ({
      showHome: true,
      showProjects: false
    }));
  }

  render() {
    const { showHome, showProjects } = this.state;
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
        <Route path="/projects" component={Projects} />

        <div className="navigation">
          <div className="navigation-sub">
            {showHome && (
              <Link
                to="/"
                className="nav-item"
                id="nav-home"
                onClick={this.handleHomeClick}
              >
                Home
              </Link>
            )}
            {showProjects && (
              <Link
                to="/projects"
                className="nav-item"
                id="nav-projects"
                onClick={this.handleProjectsClick}
              >
                Projects
              </Link>
            )}
          </div>
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}

export default Router;
```

App.js code:

```
import React from "react";
import Router from "./Router.js";
import "./App.css";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: preventing it from re-rendering... isn't the right question. The entire page is going to rerender regardless of what you do because you're reloading the page. you need it to render into the correct state. In other words, you need to preserve the state that controls the navbar displaying the way you want it to display between refreshes.

Comment: Try basing your initial state off of your browser's current location pathname, instead of hard-coded `true` or `false` values. React router provides some utilities to do this, or you can try exploring the browser's built-in API for reading the current location under `window`.

Comment: @KevinB Yes, you're right,bad choice of wording on my part.  I will look into how to preserve the state.

Comment: @veratti, thanks I will try that!